# Call an web api in pageshow event of jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am writing a JqueryMobile and jquery based web application. I have three data-pages in my index.html . I am calling an web api in pageshow event of data-page in first page and filling the list view. and then by clicking on that list itam getting an id of that list item and moving to the next page and calling again the web api to get detail of that list item in page show event. and then i am again moving to the 3rd page from detail page to call another api. It is all working fine but problem is coming when i am moving back to detail page and then from detail page to index page. on moving back pageshow event of page is calling again and it is again calling the api in all pages. If i am use oncrete then it will only call api for the very first time.
Can any body tell me how to call api in this type of structure.

Answer (score 0):

#### Have a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/tAB7x/

---

There are different ways to solve your problem, this is just one of them...

I have put the web api for filling the initial list in the 'pageinit' of the first page.  This will run exactly one when you load the page. If you require refresh of this list, you could add a refresh button.Each appended item in the list links to page2 with a query string containing the item id.  Then a click handler for the listview items is added to get the id of the clicked item and fill out the details form (page2) from web api (in the example I am just writing the id to a text box in page 2).

```
$('#page1').on('pageinit', function () {

    //get list from web api (hardcoded for this example
    var $ul = $("#dynamicList");
    $ul.append('<li><a href="#page2?id=1" class="detailLink">A</a></li>');
    $ul.append('<li><a href="#page2?id=2" class="detailLink">B</a></li>');
    $ul.append('<li><a href="#page2?id=3" class="detailLink">C</a></li>');
    $ul.listview("refresh");

    $('.detailLink').on('click', function () {
      var l = $(this).attr("href");
      l = l.substring(l.indexOf('?') + 1);
      var id = getUrlVars(l);
      $('#detalText').val(id['id']);
    });
});
```

Page2 has a button that links to page 3 and a click handler that fills out page 3 from web api (in the example I am again just writing the id to a text box in page 3):

```
$('#linkPage2').on('click', function () {
    var id = $('#detalText').val();
    $('#detalText2').val(id);
});
```

When you click the back button on either page, no code is run and the previous state of the page is maintained.